# cpp netlib with old c++ compiler

Tags: c++, linux, cpp-netlib

I am using c++ 03 compiler with cpp-netlib and on installation it gives the following error from CMake.txt

```
 No advanced standard C++ support (-std=c++11 not defined)
```

Isnt there any support of cpp-netlib on cpp03? Their documentation doesnt seem to point out anything related to compilers of C++

Comment: It would seem that the homepage makes this pretty clear in the overview: http://cpp-netlib.org/

Comment: Directly under the header "Overview" on their front page: "The project aims to build upon the latest C++ standard (currently C++11)".

Comment: So i should assume that this project is not backward compatible?